# How to expand $\frac{1}{(1-z-z^2)}$ into a power series

Tags: series-expansion

How can I get Mathematica to expand
$$\frac{1}{(1-z-z^2)}$$
into a power series so that I can pick out the coefficients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[z_] = 1/(1 - z - z^2);

coef[n_] = 
 SeriesCoefficient[f[z], {z, Infinity, n}] // 
  Simplify[#, n ∈ PositiveIntegers] &

(* (2^(-1 - 
  n) (-(-1 - Sqrt[5])^n (-1 + Sqrt[5]) - (-1 + Sqrt[5])^
    n (1 + Sqrt[5])))/Sqrt[5] *)

Sum[coef[n] z^-n, {n, 1, Infinity}] // FullSimplify // ExpandAll

(* 1/(1 - z - z^2) *)
```

**EDIT:**

The sum uses `z^-n` because the series expansion was done around `z == Infinity`. To expand around `z == 0`,

```
coef2[n_] = 
 SeriesCoefficient[f[z], {z, 0, n}] // 
  Simplify[#, n ∈ NonNegativeIntegers] &

(* 1/5 2^(-1 - 
  n) (-(1 - Sqrt[5])^n (-5 + Sqrt[5]) + (1 + Sqrt[5])^n (5 + Sqrt[5])) *)

Sum[coef2[n] z^n, {n, 0, Infinity}] // FullSimplify // ExpandAll

(* 1/(1 - z - z^2) *)
```

The sequence of coefficients start with

```
coef2 /@ Range[0, 10] // Simplify

(* {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89} *)

coef /@ Range[10] // Simplify

(* {0, -1, 1, -2, 3, -5, 8, -13, 21, -34} *)
```

**EDIT 2:** The sequence that you describe is

```
seq = {0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1};

coef3[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]

(* 1/2 (-1 - (-1)^n) *)

Sum[coef3[n] z^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]

(* 1/(-1 + z^2) *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I have two follow up questions: (1) In your verification, you used z^-n not z^n; why is that? (2) 1/(1-z-z^2) is actually the generating function for the set of all sequences of zeros and ones where ones occur only in even-length runs. coef[0] = -1, coef[1] = 0, coef[2] = -1, am I missing something?